# How to make Java HttpPost NOT include url in body

Tags: java, http

We have some old java code that POSTs some fields and values to a dotnet5 web api - The api is having problems dealing with the body of the POST as it includes the url/uri as the first part of the body.

The Java sends: `http://127.0.0.1:5555?producerRef=GREEN&systemId=78&status=false`

But the api is expecting something like: `producerRef=GREEN&systemId=78&status=false`
as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example. If we send a test message via Postman then the api has no problems.

This is the Java code:

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(queryParams.size());
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
// the address is just that, there's NO parameters 
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this.cmAddress.toURI());
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
post.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

It's quite simple, but always adds the url to the start of the body of the request. If this is the only way to produce this, what could I do to produce something that looks like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST#example

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This request seems like a GET request rather than a POST since the request params are in the URL. i don't know about the specifications of the Api you're using, but you can try [OKHTTP](https://square.github.io/okhttp/), you can easily copy the code directly from postman

Postman Get example:
[image]

Comment: Its a POST as its sending data, the params aren't in the url - thats the java httpPost adding them and the url to the body - which I don't won't.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be at below line

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(this.cmAddress.toURI());
```

This is the only place which will set the POST url ( another way is to use `setURI` which is not called anywhere in the code sample you have shared).
If you can use a debugger try checking the value of `cmAdress` variable

Comment: ok, why? this.cmAddress is just a string "http://127.0.0.1:5555", are you saying I should use setURI ?

Comment: I've tried using setURI using the above address still getting the URL in the *body*